# Query to check the full schema scan for tables in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I have a requirement to scan through the schema and identify the tables which are redundant (candidate for dropping) ,so i did a select in DBA_Dependencies to check whether the tables are being used in any of the DB object types like (Procedure, package body, views, Materialized views....) i was able to find some tables and excluded the tables ,since i also need to capture the total counts, when the table was last loaded/used is there a automated way to select only selected tables (not found in dependencies list) and capture the counts and also when it was used/loaded

Difficulty  - so many tables 500+

i have used the below query

**Query 1**

```
select table_name, 
       to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||owner||'.'||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as count
from all_tables
where owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
```

**Query 2**

```
select owner, table_name, num_rows, sample_size, last_analyzed from all_tables;
```

**Query 1 Result**

Filter Table_name=CUST_ORDER

```
OWNER TABLE_NAME COUNT SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED
ABCD  CUST_ORDER  1083     1023       01.01.2020
```

**Query 2 Result**

Filter Table_name=CUST_ORDER

```
OWNER TABLE_NAME NUM_ROWS SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANALYZED
ABCD  CUST_ORDER  1023     1023       01.01.2020
```

## Question

Query 1 - Results not matching when compared with query 2 ,since the same table and filter is applied
in both the queries and why the results are not matching ?

but when i randomly checked other filter it is matching , does any one know the reason ?

Upon further testing i encountered an error ,what does this error signify permissions ?

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04040: file **-**.csv in ****_***_***_***** not found
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
*Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.
```

Comment: This error is encountered only for specific schema not for all schemas

Answer (score 1):

The number you see on `all_tables` is a point in time capture of the number of rows.  It will only be updated if the statistics are rebuilt for that table.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT *
  FROM all_objects;

SELECT t.num_rows
  FROM all_tables t
 WHERE t.table_name = 'T1';
-- 78570

SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t1;
-- 78570
```

The stats and the physical number of rows match!

```
INSERT INTO t1
  SELECT *
    FROM all_objects ao
   WHERE rownum <= 5;
-- 5 rows inserted

SELECT t.num_rows
  FROM all_tables t
 WHERE t.table_name = 'T1';
-- 78570

SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM t1;
-- 78575
```

Here we have the mis-match because rows were inserted (or maybe even deleted), but the stats for the table have not been updated.  Let's update them:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => 'SCHEMA',
                                tabname => 'T1');
END;
/

SELECT t.num_rows
  FROM all_tables t
 WHERE t.table_name = 'T1';
-- 78575
```

Now you can see the rows match.  Using the value from `all_tables` may be good enough for your research (and will certainly be faster to query than counting every table).

Comment: Many Thanks for explanation with example it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Query - 1** is actual data of the table and hence it is accurate data. One can rely on this query's output.

**Query - 2** is not actual data. It is the data captured when table was last analyzed and one should not be dependant on this query for finding number of records in the table.

You can gather the stats on this table and execute the query-2 then you will find the same data as query-1

If records are not inserted or deleted from the table after stats are gathered, then query-1 and query-2 data will match for that table.

Comment: Many thanks this is simple and clear explanation

Comment: @rakseh Also the stats are gathered using a sampling process. Under the default settings, dbms_stats might read all the rows and capture the exact count, or it might decide to use a smaller sample and extrapolate up. The stats only need to be close enough for the optimiser to choose the best approach, and aren't expected to match the actual count every time.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Since 11g, the default statistics gathering option uses a Number of Distinct Values algorithm that scans the whole table and will always return an accurate number of rows. (Although other statistics information, like histograms, may use a separate pass and sampling.)

Comment: @JonHeller I'd noticed it tended to give an exact count but I didn't know it was guaranteed. Thanks!